# PayPal Future Payment returns 'approval_url'

Tags: paypal, payment, future

I'm currently attempting to integrate my app with Future Payments and in the documentation, it mentions:

> Unlike the standard REST API docs that demonstrate a one time payment,
>   a future payment doesn't require you to separately get payment
>   approval after getting initial user consent. The payment is
>   pre-approved by the user.

So looking at the example, I should get a response which contains:

```
"state": "authorized"
"links": [
                            {
                                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/4TD55050SV609544L",
                                "method": "GET",
                                "rel": "self"
                            },
                            {
                                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/4TD55050SV609544L/capture",
                                "method": "POST",
                                "rel": "capture"
                            },
                            {
                                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/4TD55050SV609544L/void",
                                "method": "POST",
                                "rel": "void"
                            },
                            {
                                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/4TD55050SV609544L/reauthorize",
                                "method": "POST",
                                "rel": "reauthorize"
                            },
                            {
                                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-2C433581AX997613HKJFBVLI",
                                "method": "GET",
                                "rel": "parent_payment"
                            }
                        ],
```

And from what I understand, the transaction, along with the Client Metadata ID and Access Token in the request header, should be automatically processed, without further approval, because the user has already given consent.

So if the transaction intent is 'sale', the success response 'state' would be 'completed' and if the intent is 'authorize', the state would be 'authorized'.

This makes sense, but when testing my app, I'm getting a response with an approval url that I need to redirect the user to and the state is 'created' not 'completed/authorized'  ? -

```
"state": "created"
"create_time": "2016-03-20T00:42:25Z",
"links": [
                           {
                             "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3NA62949E72063722K3W7D4I",
                             "rel": "self",
                             "method": "GET"
                            },
                            {
                              "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-41A06151Y6402822R",
                              "rel": "approval_url",
                              "method": "REDIRECT"
                            },
                            {
                              "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3NA62949E72063722K3W7D4I/execute",
                              "rel": "execute",
                              "method": "POST"
                            }
               ]
```

Comment: Not quite sure why the downvote, I thought this was a fair question.

Comment: I don't quite understand why this was downvoted either, so I gave it a vote up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by removing express_checkout from the scope. If this is enabled, it appears to override future payments so it no longer works and uses the express checkout pay flow instead.